# Problems with the hyperlinks and the acronyms with acro

Tags: acronyms, hyperlink

I am using the acro package to print my list of acronyms in my table of contents. However, I also want to link the words in the content when I use \ac to the respective acronym in the list. How could I do it? I do not want the page number in the list though. Here are my codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{acro,hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\usepackage{dcolumn} %% Chapter 2, format D{}{}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{}

\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}


\acsetup{make-links=true}
\acsetup{list/display=all}

%Adding my tex file with my list of acronyms


\DeclareAcronym{NOC}
{class = A,
    long=National Oil Company,
     short={NOC}
}


\DeclareAcronym{PDVSA}
{class = A,
    long=Petróleos de Venezuela Sociedad Anónima,
     short=PDVSA
}


\DeclareAcronym{YPFB}
{class = A,
    long=Yacimientos Petrolíferos Fiscales Bolivanos,
     short={YPFB}
}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Acronyms}
\printacronyms[include-classes=A,name=List of Acronyms,heading=chapter*, template=toc,display=all,sort=true]



\chapter{National Oil Companies}
The Bolivian \ac{NOC}, \ac{YPFB}, has played a supervisory role in the industry. In contrast, Venezuela's \ac{PDVSA} plays a direct role in the exploitation of its oil fields.

\end{document}
```

Comment: your example can't be used for a test as you load a local file.

Comment: I have added more information to my post. I hope it helps!

Comment: that doesn't compile in a current tex system (even if I add the missing bracket). include-classes is not known.

Comment: Try it again and let me know. I could run it with Overleaf.